# Why is the data parsed by pugixml lost in another function?

Tags: c++, c, xml, xml-parsing, pugixml

I have 2 functions:

```
void XMLParser::ParseScene(const char* path)
{
    // Load the XML file
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file(path);

    scene = doc.child("scene");
}
```

and

```
void XMLParser::CreateModelLights(pugi::xml_node node)
{
    GLuint i = 0;
    for (pugi::xml_node entity : node.children())
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I am calling `parser.ParseScene("src/xml/scene.xml");` to generate `parser.scene` and then call `parser.CreateModelLights(parser.scene);`, but it gives me rubbish data in `node` parameter / `parser.scene`.

If I put `scene = doc.child("scene");` on `CreateModelLight()` first line it will parse my data ok in `parser.scene`, but I don't want to force the node like that because I am calling the function recursively. Ideally I want to parse my XML in `ParseScene()` and then store it a `pugi::xml_node` variable declared in the header that I can use in functions like `CreateModelLights()`.

XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scene>
    [...]
</scene>
```

Rubbish data I get:
[image: bad data]

Data I should get:
[image: good data]

Comment: This is a "dangling pointer" problem in disguise: All `pugi::xml_node` objects reference data inside the `pugi::xml_document`. You are expected to keep the `pugi::xml_document` alive for as long as you have  `pugi::xml_node` objects that point into it.

Comment: I see. So if I allocate the document dynamically and destroy the document, when I'm done I shouldn't encounter this problem again, right?

Comment: Correct. It could be as simple as making `doc` a member of `XMLParser`.

Comment: @Botje It has worked as expected. Can you please post an answer so I can vote is as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not terribly clear in the documentation, but PugiXML uses a fairly common memory management pattern: The `pugi::xml_document` *owns* the entire XML DOM tree, and `pugi::xml_node` objects are just shallow pointers into this tree.

This means that you need to keep the `pugi::xml_document` object alive for as long as there are `pugi::xml_node` objects pointing into it. Probably the quickest way is to promote `doc` to a member variable.